# How to let Perl recognize both lower and uppercase input?

Tags: perl

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can make my perl script accept both the lowercase and uppercase variant of a letter.

For Example.

```
my %channels = (a => 'test', b => 'test2', c => 'test3', d => 'test4', e => 'test5', f => 'test6', g => 'test7');
```

So when I want to enter test I can either do a or A and it will accept it

To Sum up the problem:

When running the script I ran into an issue where you had to input a if you wanted test. This is all fine to me but other people wanted the option to do capital A instead. I am trying to give them the option to do either.

Thanks All

Comment: If you are comparing, use  /i expression. This will lead to case insensitive comparison.

Comment: I am really new to perl what exactly would this look like?

Comment: if (lc($value) eq lc("Anon"))  what it basically does is, converts your input string and the string to compare with to lower case, and no matter what you enter, it accepts it. Also check the responses given by other guys below. They have pointed out some neat examples as well.

Answer (score 2):

For your hash keys (**single alphabet as a key**) try the logical defined operator.

> // => logical defined operator. If the left hand side is true give the result else if evaluate the right side.

```
print $channels{$input} // $channels{lc($input)};
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution for your input

```
print $channels{lc($input)};
```

If the input is uppercase it will convert to lowercase. Don't get worry about lowercase characters.

Comment: This one. Have your keys in your code be all lower case, and then lowercase the input when using it to look up the key in your hash.  No need to be complex.

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully clear what your requirement is but from the example it looks like you are asking for a hash which is case insensitive regarding the keys, i.e. that  `$hash{foo}`, `$hash{FoO}` etc all result in the same value.

This can be implemented with [tied hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) by defining appropriate `FETCH`,`STORE` and `DELETE` methods for the hash. And there are already implementations which do this, like [Hash::Case](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Hash-Case/lib/Hash/Case.pod).

Of course you could also simply normalize all keys (lower case, upper case etc) before accessing the hash.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep all the hash keys lower case and convert the input value keys to lower case:

```
for my $inputKey ('a', 'A', 'b', 'B') {
    print $channels{lc($inputKey)}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `regex` it's not shorter but another way to solve it:

```
my %hash = {a => 'test', b => 'test2'};
my $read_input;

foreach my $key (keys %hash){
  if($key =~ /${read_input}/i){ #note the i for 'ignore case'
    print $hash{$key}; 
  }
}
```

You basically iterate through the keys of your hash and compare them against the input. If you found the right one you can print the value.

But nevertheless: You may just convert every input to lower case and then access the hash.